# Javascript Closures are not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I'm trying to implement clojure in javascript. Can anyone see what the problem is?

```js
 var a = (
          function()
          {
            var privateFunction = function()
                                  {
                                    alert('Hello');
                                  }
    
            var OsmanFunction = function()
                                  {
                                    alert('Osman');
                                  }
          return
                {
                 publicFunction: function()
                                 {
                                   privateFunction(); 
                                 }
    
                 OsmanFunction: function()
                                 {
                                   OsmanFunction(); 
                                 }
       }})();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
    
    <body>
    <p> <a href="#" id="hitme" onclick="a.OsmanFunction()">Please hit me</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is your code so poorly formatted?

Comment: `return` what is this doing there?

Comment: @Krishnachandra Sharma It's a self-executing function that creates a closure and returns an object with 2 functions.

Comment: @DanielT. with a newline object correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need formatting your code. Really.

```
var a = (
    function () {
        var privateFunction = function () {
            alert('Hello');
        };

        var OsmanFunction = function () {
            alert('Osman');
        };
        return {
            publicFunction: function() {
                privateFunction();
            },
            OsmanFunction: function() {
                OsmanFunction();
            }
        };
    })();

 document.getElementById("hitme").addEventListener('click', a.OsmanFunction);
```

This is working version.

But... in your code:

```
return
            {
```

You can't transfer return object to the next line.

You have no "," on return object between functions

```
{
             publicFunction: function()
                             {
                               privateFunction(); 
                             }

             OsmanFunction: function()
                             {
                               OsmanFunction(); 
                             }
   }
```

a is not defined.
Please, in fature be attentive to your code, you make code for an other developers, who will support your project, not for machines.

Comment: To elaborate, Javascript is sensitive to new lines for certain operators. `return` is one of them.

Comment: In JS semicolons are required... but it also includes something called [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) that tries to guess where you should have put one and inserts it for you. What happened here is when it saw `return` on a line by itself it inserted a semicolon after it `return;` so your function effectively did `return undefined;`. With `return` the thing you are returning must always start on the same line as `return`. Learning to use a linter like [jsHint](http://jshint.com/) can help to spot these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning undefined (returning nothing, which is `undefined` in js). The lines:

```
return
{
  publicFunction: function()
  {
    privateFunction(); 
  },
  OsmanFunction: function()
  {
    OsmanFunction(); 
  }
}
```

Is interpreted as:

```
return;

{
  publicFunction: function()
  {
    privateFunction(); 
  },
  OsmanFunction: function()
  {
    OsmanFunction(); 
  }
};
```

Therefore it is equivalent to:

```
return undefined;

{
  publicFunction: function()
  {
    privateFunction(); 
  },
  OsmanFunction: function()
  {
    OsmanFunction(); 
  }
};
```

Be very careful with line breaks in javascript. If possible use a coding convention that avoids this kind of mistake. There are several coding conventions that work. Google "Crockford convention" or "standard.js". Either convention work so choose one that you like.

Anyway. I'd suggest you don't start an open brace `{` in a new line if possible. Get used to starting a brace at the end of the line. It avoids this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was just poor formatting, but this is I think what your trying to achieve.

```js
function Test(){

  var privateFunction = function(){
      alert('Hello');
  }

  var OsmanFunction = function(){
    alert('Osman');
  }
  return {
    publicFunction: privateFunction //NB This is no longer private if you expose it
    , OsmanFunction: OsmanFunction
  }

 };
 
var tester = Test();
var btn = document.getElementById('hitme');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  tester.OsmanFunction()
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<p> <a href="#" id="hitme">Please hit me</a></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, you missed comma between "publicFunction" and "OsmanFunction" when these returning:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<script>
a = (
    function() {
        var privateFunction = function() {
            alert('Hello');
        }

        var OsmanFunction = function() {
            alert('Osman');
        }
        return {
            publicFunction: function() {
                privateFunction();
            },
            OsmanFunction: function() {
                 OsmanFunction();
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p> <a href="#" id="hitme" onclick="a.OsmanFunction()">Please hit me</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```